# What Would be the Big O Time Complexity of this Greedy Search for TSP?

Tags: big-o, traveling-salesman

I just want some clarification/reassurance, looking at the code on this GitHub [here](https://github.com/ccmxy/Greedy-Traveling-Salesman-Problem/blob/master/simpleGreedy.py), would the Big O notation for the time complexity by On2, as it is directly proportional to the amount of vertices/cities in the problem?

Comment: O(N2) * I meant to say

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code relies on a distance matrix of cities:

```
def getDistanceMatrix(cities):
    distanceMatrix = []
    for currentNode in cities:
        subArray = []
        for comparisonNode in cities:
            subArray.append(getDistanceBetweenTwoCities(currentNode, comparisonNode))
        distanceMatrix.append(subArray)
    return distanceMatrix
```

It is thus of order `O(n^2)` where `n` is the number of cities.